# How to insert a column of characters to a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, character

I'd like to insert a column of character to a matrix in MATLAB.

For example, we want to reach from first matrix to the second matrix:

```
first_matrix = [2  3; 4  5; 1  7]       
second_matrix = [c  2  3; c  4  5; c  1  7]
```

In fact the reason is that, I have a `output.txt` file from a software. In that file, I should select a matrix in it, and change matrix column order. After doing this, i.e. reach to `first_matrix`, the output in form of `second_matrix` should be used in another software. So, finally I should save it in a text file format for second software.

Comment: What language are you using? What is your intended outcome? Please check out [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do with this numeric arrays. The possible ways to do this are:

1. Using a [categorical array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-categorical-arrays.html) i.e.

   ```
   >> second_matrix = [num2cell(repmat('c',3,1)) categorical(first_matrix)]

   ans = 

     3×3 categorical array

        c      2      3 
        c      4      5 
        c      1      7
   ```
2. Using a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) i.e.

   ```
   >> second_matrix = [repmat('c  ',3,1) num2str(first_matrix)]

   second_matrix =

      3×7 char array

      'c  2  3'
      'c  4  5'
      'c  1  7'
   ```
3. Using a [string array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) (requires ≥ R2016b) i.e.

   ```
   >> second_matrix = [repmat("c",3,1) first_matrix]   %in ≥ R2017a
    % second_matrix = [repmat(string('c'),3,1) first_matrix]   %in ≥ R2016b

   second_matrix = 

     3×3 string array

       "c"    "2"    "3"
       "c"    "4"    "5"
       "c"    "1"    "7"
   ```
4. Using a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html) i.e.

   ```
   >> second_matrix = [num2cell(repmat('c',3,1)) num2cell(first_matrix)]]

   second_matrix =

      3×3 cell array

        {'c'}    {[2]}    {[3]}
        {'c'}    {[4]}    {[5]}
        {'c'}    {[1]}    {[7]}
   ```
5. Using a [symbolic array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-matrices.html) (requires Symbolic Math Toolbox) i.e.

   ```
   >> second_matrix = [repmat(sym('c'),3,1) first_matrix]

   second_matrix =

   [ c, 2, 3]
   [ c, 4, 5]
   [ c, 1, 7]
   ```